# XSLT Copy When Using For-Each

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to attempt to format a webservice call. I am able to copy the "Header" elements to the translated document, however I am not able to copy the line item fields. I am utilizing the for-each command, however it does not loop through the data.

The XML that I am passing in looks like:

```
<OTC_Alerts_KNA>
   <Header>
      <current_date_time_of_application_server__c>2015-04-08T12:48:50</current_date_time_of_application_server__c>
      <alert_type__c>LSH</alert_type__c>
      <single_character_indicator__c>O</single_character_indicator__c>
      <alert_functional_area__c>DELV</alert_functional_area__c>
      <customer_number__c>1000000118</customer_number__c>
      <customer_name__c>WEBCO HAWAII</customer_name__c>
      <sales_document_number__c>0000012164</sales_document_number__c>
      <sales_document_type__c>ZOR</sales_document_type__c>
   </Header>
   <Line_Items>
      <customer_purchase_order_number__c>LDSHORTAGE11</customer_purchase_order_number__c>
      <requested_delivery_date__c>2015-04-01</requested_delivery_date__c>
      <material_number__c>000000000100100010</material_number__c>
      <short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>SPK RED BRY 12 oz1</short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>
      <free_msg_text__c>000010</free_msg_text__c>
      <confirmed_quantity__c>10</confirmed_quantity__c>
      <pick_quantity__c>10</pick_quantity__c>
   </Line_Items>
   <Line_Items>
      <customer_purchase_order_number__c>LDSHORTAGE11</customer_purchase_order_number__c>
      <requested_delivery_date__c>2015-04-01</requested_delivery_date__c>
      <material_number__c>000000000100100003</material_number__c>
      <short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>RICE KRPS 12CT/CS</short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>
      <free_msg_text__c>000020</free_msg_text__c>
      <confirmed_quantity__c>10</confirmed_quantity__c>
      <pick_quantity__c>10</pick_quantity__c>
   </Line_Items>
</OTC_Alerts_KNA>
```

My XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="urn:create">
        <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:iDoc__c">
            <xsl:copy-of select="OTC_Alerts_KNA/Header/node()" />
        </urn:sObjects>
        <xsl:for-each select="OTC_Alerts_KNA/Line_Items">
            <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:iDoc_Line_Item__c">
<xsl:copy-of select="OTC_Alerts_KNA/Line_Items/node()" />
            </urn:sObjects>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output that I am getting is below.

```
<urn:create
    xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <urn:sObjects
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xsi:type="urn1:iDoc__c">
        <current_date_time_of_application_server__c>2015-04-08T12:48:50</current_date_time_of_application_server__c>
        <alert_type__c>LSH</alert_type__c>
        <single_character_indicator__c>O</single_character_indicator__c>
        <alert_functional_area__c>DELV</alert_functional_area__c>
        <customer_number__c>1000000118</customer_number__c>
        <customer_name__c>WEBCO HAWAII</customer_name__c>
        <sales_document_number__c>0000012164</sales_document_number__c>
        <sales_document_type__c>ZOR</sales_document_type__c>
    </urn:sObjects>
    <urn:sObjects
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xsi:type="urn1:iDoc_Line_Item__c"/>
    <urn:sObjects
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xsi:type="urn1:iDoc_Line_Item__c"/>
</urn:create>
```

As you can see, the "OTC_Alerts_KNA/Header" nodes are copied, however, the line items are not copied. I would like each "Line_Item" element copied, along with its children. What I would like to see is:

```
<urn:create xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <urn:sObjects xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="urn1:iDoc__c">
      <current_date_time_of_application_server__c>2015-04-08T12:48:50</current_date_time_of_application_server__c>
      <alert_type__c>LSH</alert_type__c>
      <single_character_indicator__c>O</single_character_indicator__c>
      <alert_functional_area__c>DELV</alert_functional_area__c>
      <customer_number__c>1000000118</customer_number__c>
      <customer_name__c>WEBCO HAWAII</customer_name__c>
      <sales_document_number__c>0000012164</sales_document_number__c>
      <sales_document_type__c>ZOR</sales_document_type__c>
   </urn:sObjects>
   <urn:sObjects xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="urn1:iDoc_Line_Item__c">
      <customer_purchase_order_number__c>LDSHORTAGE11</customer_purchase_order_number__c>
      <requested_delivery_date__c>2015-04-01</requested_delivery_date__c>
      <material_number__c>000000000100100010</material_number__c>
      <short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>SPK RED BRY 12 oz1</short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>
      <free_msg_text__c>000010</free_msg_text__c>
      <confirmed_quantity__c>10</confirmed_quantity__c>
      <pick_quantity__c>10</pick_quantity__c>
   </urn:sObjects>
   <urn:sObjects xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="urn1:iDoc_Line_Item__c">
      <customer_purchase_order_number__c>LDSHORTAGE11</customer_purchase_order_number__c>
      <requested_delivery_date__c>2015-04-01</requested_delivery_date__c>
      <material_number__c>000000000100100003</material_number__c>
      <short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>RICE KRPS 12CT/CS</short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>
      <free_msg_text__c>000020</free_msg_text__c>
      <confirmed_quantity__c>10</confirmed_quantity__c>
      <pick_quantity__c>10</pick_quantity__c>
   </urn:sObjects>
</urn:create>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
<xsl:for-each select="OTC_Alerts_KNA/Line_Items">
    <!-- context is now at the <Line_Items> node! -->
    <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:iDoc_Line_Item__c">
        <!-- there is no <OTC_Alerts_KNA> beneath <Line_Items> -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="OTC_Alerts_KNA/Line_Items/node()" />
    </urn:sObjects>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You *could* fix it by using the right context

```
<xsl:for-each select="OTC_Alerts_KNA/Line_Items">
    <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:iDoc_Line_Item__c">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
    </urn:sObjects>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**However,** I recommend you do not use `<xsl:for-each>` for this problem.

Use the a transformation based on the identity template and a few specialized templates that handle one case each:

```
<xsl:transform
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
  xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="OTC_Alerts_KNA">
    <urn:create>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </urn:create>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="Header">
    <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:iDoc__c">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </urn:sObjects>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Line_Items">
    <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:iDoc_Line_Item__c">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </urn:sObjects>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

gives you

```
<urn:create xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
            xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:iDoc__c">
      <current_date_time_of_application_server__c>2015-04-08T12:48:50</current_date_time_of_application_server__c>
      <alert_type__c>LSH</alert_type__c>
      <single_character_indicator__c>O</single_character_indicator__c>
      <alert_functional_area__c>DELV</alert_functional_area__c>
      <customer_number__c>1000000118</customer_number__c>
      <customer_name__c>WEBCO HAWAII</customer_name__c>
      <sales_document_number__c>0000012164</sales_document_number__c>
      <sales_document_type__c>ZOR</sales_document_type__c>
   </urn:sObjects>
   <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:iDoc_Line_Item__c">
      <customer_purchase_order_number__c>LDSHORTAGE11</customer_purchase_order_number__c>
      <requested_delivery_date__c>2015-04-01</requested_delivery_date__c>
      <material_number__c>000000000100100010</material_number__c>
      <short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>SPK RED BRY 12 oz1</short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>
      <free_msg_text__c>000010</free_msg_text__c>
      <confirmed_quantity__c>10</confirmed_quantity__c>
      <pick_quantity__c>10</pick_quantity__c>
   </urn:sObjects>
   <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:iDoc_Line_Item__c">
      <customer_purchase_order_number__c>LDSHORTAGE11</customer_purchase_order_number__c>
      <requested_delivery_date__c>2015-04-01</requested_delivery_date__c>
      <material_number__c>000000000100100003</material_number__c>
      <short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>RICE KRPS 12CT/CS</short_text_for_sales_order_item__c>
      <free_msg_text__c>000020</free_msg_text__c>
      <confirmed_quantity__c>10</confirmed_quantity__c>
      <pick_quantity__c>10</pick_quantity__c>
   </urn:sObjects>
</urn:create>
```

The "identity template" based approach gives you

- increased modularity
- increased re-usability
- less nesting
- better extensibility (Need to modify a node? Add a template just for that case. Need to remove a node entirely from the output? Add an empty template like this one: `<xsl:template match="free_msg_text__c" />` - done. )

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a better response. I have used your suggested template and everything appears to be working properly.